# Segmentation fault in malloc:

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, malloc

assign malloc() returnd value to a function parameter then access to outside of that function... what`s wrong here? MY sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student{
    double cgpa;
    int id;
    char name[100];

};

void init(student *ptr)
{
    ptr = (struct student*)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    ptr->id = 1;
    ptr->cgpa = 4.00;
    sprintf(ptr->name,"murad");
    printf("In Initfunc:\nname %s\nid %d\ncgpa %lf\n",ptr->name,ptr->id,ptr->cgpa);
}

int main()
{
    struct student *murad;
    init(murad);
    printf("IN Main:\nname %s\nid %d\ncgpa %lf\n",murad->name,murad->id,murad->cgpa);
    free(murad);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: BTW, if you compile this using a C compiler, just remove this useless cast of malloc's result.

Comment: This `void init(student *ptr)` is not valid C. If this compiles, you seem to be compiling using a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("IN Main:\nname %s\nid %d\ncgpa %lf\n",murad->name,murad->id,murad->cgpa);
```

This is causing error. As you allocate memory to struct pointer inside function which is copy of `murad` you pass as argument. So no memory is allocated to pointer in `main` and you *dereference un-initialized pointer causeing undefined behaviour* .

You need to `return` pointer from function to `main`.

So your program can go like this -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student{
    double cgpa;
    int id;
    char name[100];
};

struct student * init(void)   // <-- No need to pass any parameter
{
    struct student *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    ptr->id = 1;
    ptr->cgpa = 4.00;
    sprintf(ptr->name,"murad");
    printf("In Initfunc:\nname %s\nid %d\ncgpa %lf\n",ptr->name,ptr->id,ptr->cgpa);
    return ptr;          // <--- return pointer 
}

int main()
{
    struct student *murad;
    murad=init();
    printf("IN Main:\nname %s\nid %d\ncgpa %lf\n",murad->name,murad->id,murad->cgpa);
    free(murad);
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not returning the new pointer.
Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student{
    double cgpa;
    int id;
    char name[100];

};

void init(struct student **ptr)
{
    struct student *temp;
    *ptr = (struct student*)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    temp = *ptr;
    temp->id = 1;
    temp->cgpa = 4.00;
    sprintf(temp->name,"murad");
    printf("In Initfunc:\nname %s\nid %d\ncgpa %lf\n",temp->name,temp->id,temp->cgpa);
}

int main()
{
    struct student *murad;
    init(&murad);
    printf("IN Main:\nname %s\nid %d\ncgpa %lf\n",murad->name,murad->id,murad->cgpa);
    free(murad);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice the use of double pointer in init

Comment: You're not returning the new pointer either.

Comment: @juanchopanza: "*returning*" in this context is ambiguous.

Comment: @alk I don't think so but whatever.

Comment: @alk mind to explain the ambiguously?

Comment: "*returning*" via a `return` statement or via assigning it to `*ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are assigning the result of `malloc` to the local variable `ptr` which is only available in the scope of `init`. You are not assigning it to the local variable `murad` in the scope of `main`.

It'd probably be better to return `ptr` as a result from `init`

Also, please do not cast the result of malloc. It is poor style and potentially dangerous.